# Topological spaces made by identifying opposite faces of a cube?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, reference-request

My bashful, nameless, colleague asked me:

When you identify opposite faces of a square, then depending on where you twist or not, you get a torus, Klein bottle, or projective plane.

> What spaces can you get when identifying opposite faces of a cube?

He was hoping for a reference.

Comment: Of course, if you do the same with a dodecahedron with the correct twist, you famously get the Poincare homology sphere!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_sphere#Poincar.C3.A9_homology_sphere

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The ones that are manifolds were considered by Poincaré, and a nice discussion is on [this page of the Manifold Atlas](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Poincar%C3%A9%27s_cube_manifolds).

Comment: Many good answers, but I guess this is the most directly related one.

Answer (score 16):

- B. Everitt. *3-manifolds from platonic solids*.  Topology and its applications, 2004.

Covers everything you're asking for and more.

Comment: This is wonderful!

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 4 of ["Topology Now!" by Messer & Straffin](http://people.albion.edu/ram/TopologyNow!/) gives a good undergraduate level overview of the topic of gluing polyhedral solids.

Answer (score 3):

You (or the bashful colleague) might want to look at Cannon/Floyd/Parry's program to analyze spaces of this ilk: http://www.math.vt.edu/people/floyd/research/software/twist.html